# Using EntityGraph with Hibernate Search ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm trying to eliminate loading of unnecessary data when I find some entities using [Hibernate Search ORM](http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.8/). The projections mechanizm provided by the framework is not convinient because of it's limitations(e.g. all the data you need must be stored in index).

Is there any way to use an `EntityGraph` for loading entities with `FullTextEntityManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to define most of your relations as lazy, and use an entity graph when you need to fetch more.

Hibernate Search does not allow to use an `EntityGraph`, at least not yet, but it allows you to set a `Criteria` object on your query, and you can use `org.hibernate.Criteria#setFetchMode` to disable fetching for some associations.

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_fetching_strategy